# How to translate html, css and js into one javascript (animation)

Tags: javascript, css, jsfiddle

I made this script but now I want it as one javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/SamuraiFox/p9sDB/

Or at least "translate" this part into javascript:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
```

Comment: Without jQuery? Also out of curiosity why do you want to do this in javascript? Css animations are much more powerful/fast.

Comment: Their fiddle uses jQuery

Comment: well...I have this other code that is js not css...http://jsfiddle.net/SamuraiFox/PcqDB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$("#circle").animate({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  }, 1000);
```

You could also add an 'easing' attribute if you need to play with it. You'd have to install a jQuery easing plugin though, like this one : http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

By default, jQuery's easing method is `swing`. `linear` is also implemented in jQuery.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/p9sDB/4/

Comment: If I understood the question correctly this is correct answer +1

Answer (score 0):

you can just add the css per javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/p9sDB/5/

```
function resize() {
    $("#circle").css({
        "transition": "all 1s ease",
        "width": "0px",
        "height": "0px"
    });
}
```

it is recommended to use css-animations instead of jQuery `animate`

Comment: How would you randomly generate circles in canvas...with css? 
http://jsfiddle.net/SamuraiFox/PcqDB/